# Would removing custom dimensions from GA improve page speed?

Tags: google-analytics, pagespeed-insights

I inherited an older GA account and noticed the previous user has quite a few custom dimensions. Because custom dimensions are a "hit" on a page, would removing the custom dimensions improve page speed, albeit if even a small amount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom dimensions are usually sent along with either event, pageview or transaction hits.

Removing custom dimensions from GA would not net you any savings in terms of page performance.

What might yield some performance increase is if you:

- removing the capturing of the custom dimension along with code required to come up with the value of the custom dimension for collection from the pages you're capturing these dimensions.
- Removing the events/hits associated with capturing these custom dimensions.

Overall, just deleting/deactivating them from GA web UI will not have any effect on your page speed performance.